# mysql error log issue

Tags: mysql, logs, mysql-5.5, my.cnf

I have mysql server running successfully.
The error log location is as..

```
mysql> show variables like '%log_erro%';
+---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| log_error     | /var/log/mysql/err.log |
+---------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The issue am facing is that when i am changing the `error log location` from above to some other location by changing from `my.cnf`  and then restarting the server but the error log is not getting generated and servers starts successfully.

**EDIT**

After restarting the server the value of the above variable get changed.
but i didn't found the error log in that location.

Comment: Hello Abdul, silly question, but did you make sure that MySQL has rights in the other location to write and read?

Comment: @CraigEfrein : yes the folder under which the error log is to be generated have owner:group as mysql:mysql and having correct permissions also..

Comment: @CraigEfrein : I have this problem not with all mysql servers.this is what i am facing first time i know how to change the variables from my.cnf.

Comment: Well, lets say you wanted to put the error log in /opt/log/mysql for example.   1. mkdir -p /opt/log/mysql  2. chown mysql:mysql -R /opt/log/mysql 3. Edit my.cnf and change log_error to /opt/log/mysql.  Make sure that log_error is under the [mysqld] section.  Then restart mysql

Comment: @CraigEfrein : I have done all this but not found the log file.

Comment: I wonder if you're my.cnf file is even being loaded.  If you change the log_error directory in my.cnf, does it show up correctly in "show variables" ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2293/discussion-between-craig-efrein-and-abdul-manaf)

Comment: Give some wrong value or invalid MySQL variable name and restart MySQL server  it will fail and log that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have placed the log-error option under the wrong header.

Put it here:

```
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysql/err.log
```

Then, `service mysql restart`

I put it there because the mysql service in /etc/init.d calls mysqld_safe to call mysqld. In addition, /etc/init.d/mysql can pass paramaters to mysqld_safe as shown above.

Just to be safe, run this also

```
mkdir /var/log/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
```

Give it a Try !!!